# Nested Mongo Query from CLI

Tags: mongodb

For the following data (taken from [MongoDB in Action](http://www.manning.com/banker/)), how can I query in Mongo Shell to get the `addresses.street` for any document (in my case it's only 1 here) where the `addresses.home` equals "home"?

Desired result: `{"street" : "1 E. 23rd Street"}`

```
{ _id: ObjectId("4c4b1476238d3b4dd5000001")
username: "kbanker",
addresses: [
{ 
  name: "home",
  street: "588 5th Street",
  city: "Brooklyn",
  state: "NY",
  zip: 11215},
{ 
  name: "work",
  street: "1 E. 23rd Street",
  city: "New York",
  state "NY",
  zip 10010},
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use $elemMatch in projection mode : [DOCS](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/)

```
db.collection.find({},{addresses: {$elemMatch:{'name':'home'}}, 'addresses.street':1, _id:0})
{ "addresses" : [ { "street" : "588 5th Street" } ] }
```